# Sending data from jQuery Post to Python script

Tags: jquery, python, cgi

I want to send a string from the front-end to my backend Python script. This is how I send the data using jQuery

```
$.ajax({
url:"more.py",
type: "POST",
data:{data:"american"},
dataType: "json",
contentType: "application/json",
success:function(data){}
});
```

This is how I attempt to access my data in the backend

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import json
import cgi
from bson.json_util import dumps
from bson import json_util
#print "Content-type: application/json\n\n";
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";


form = cgi.FieldStorage()
city = form.getvalue('data')
print city
```

What am i doing wrong? I am unable to retrieve the value of data by this method.

Comment: You need to have a socket or web/application server listening at the backend to use AJAX.